# How to configure Dragon Dictate so that it does not scan files upon opening?

Tags: macos, textedit, voice-dictation

When I open a text file with [TextEdit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextEdit), Dragon Dictate scan the file:

[image]

It often ends up being unresponsive if the file is large. How to configure Dragon Dictate so that it does not scan files upon opening?

I use Dragon Dictate 5 with OS X 10.10. If I open the file SublimeText, I do not have this issue.

Comment: I have an earlier major version and that doesn't happen for me, probably not a feature in the version I'm running.  That said, I did check Dragon Dictate > Preferences... and saw nothing in there however since you didn't mention whether or not you looked there, well did you?

Comment: @user3439894 same here, I didn't have this issue with Dragon Dictate 4. Dragon Dictate > Preferences is still impressively desert.

Comment: I guess I didn't look to well the first time and upon second glance I found the setting to change to stop that behavior.  See my answer below.  I checked the TextEdit check box and then opened a 40MB text file and up came that message box... system froze... had to force quit Dragon Dictate. :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate that behavior in an earlier major version and to stop it, this is what I did.

Go to **Dragon Dictate > Preferences... > Dictation** and uncheck the **TextEdit** check box, as shown in the image below.

[image: Dragon Dictate > Preferences... > Dictation]

*Note: This is from Dragon Dictate 3.0.2 and may be somewhat different in version 5, however hopefully this will help to resolve the issue.*